# Getting started with C#, how to Debug .NET 4.0 MVC3 Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to self teach myself C# and wondering if anyone can help me with what seems to be a basic C# question. I created a C# file with this code, started debugging but don’t see “Hello World” anywhere.

```
using System;
class Hello
{
   static void Main() {
      Console.WriteLine("hello, world");
   }
}
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664628(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664628%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

So I guess my question is this. Where should I expect to see “Hello World”? I have checked the Console and the Browser. Is there some setup that needs to be done to properly debug C# files. I am probably missing the big picture as to how C# works. I am use to PHP where I can just do something like this...

```
<?php
   include 'my file';
   echo 'my file included';
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks everybody for all of the help. You have all helped me understand and realize a number of things about C# / .NET. After extensive troubleshooting it is evident that the problem is not a mater of the debugging working, but the fact that my C# file doesn't appear to be properly hooked/included (not sure what its called in .NET terms) to the rest of the project. Anyways I am accepting **keyboardP's** answer as he answered first and technically gave me all the right answers. Also thanks to **dasblinkenlight** who was also extra helpful.

Additional Solution:

After insight from SO users. This article helped point me in the right direction.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: the php sample you're included is equivalent to an asp.net c# application.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't choose "Console application", when you started the new project. Try opening the command prompt, use it to navigate to your binary (usually located in `[project root]\bin\Debug`) and start your application from the console.

Comment: you make me doubt : You created a Console application project, didn't you ?

Comment: I did my project as ASP.NET MVC3 using VS 2010

Comment: The reason you are seeing "Hello World" on the page is not your writting the string to the page.

Comment: I apologize for being a complete noob but how would I write the string to the page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because the command prompt window is immediately closing. You can avoid this by adding `Console.ReadLine();` after your `WriteLine` statement. This will wait for you to press return before closing the prompt window.

Alternatively, assuming you're using Visual Studio, you can run the build without a debugger attached by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

**Edit** - Based on the extra information added that you're using ASP.NET and not a console application.

Firstly, what are you trying to achieve? If you want to output debug information, then you can `Debug.WriteLine` instead of `Console.WriteLine`

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

This will output the text to the "Output" window at the bottom of Visual Studio (by default).

**Edit 2** Since you just want to write random text to the page, you can use

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Hello World");
```

There are [sometimes issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866025/sp2010-httpcontext-response-write-not-working-for-linkbuttons-onclick-event) with `Response.Write` but it should be okay for what you want to do here.

Comment: You should read his comments in his original post. he did not make a console app, it is a ASP.NET page.

Comment: I most be missing something fundamentally obvious because this is not working for me. The message should appear in the output, is that correct?

Comment: @japanFour You are not seeing it written to the console because you *did not make a console application* you made a web page.

Comment: @japanFour - I've updated the answer. What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to output debug information or are you trying to display text on a webpage that users will see?

Comment: Preferably I would like to do both at some point. But ultimately I am just trying to make sure I am actually using the file to test my code.

Comment: @japanFour - I've updated the answer. Try using `Response.Write`.

Comment: I inserted Response.Write inside my class and VS tells me "The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @japanFour Try using `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write()`.

Comment: Hmm. No errors. But still no message anywhere. I really appreciate all the help regardless.

Comment: @japanFour - I just tried `Response.Write` and it works fine. Your project setup just seems incorrect and you shouldn't have a `Main` method present. Are you sure you created an `ASP.NET MVC` project and not a `Console/WinForm` one? I suggest going through [tutorials first](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3)

Comment: Positive I created a ASP.NET MVC project. I think the issue is my new C# file isn't properly hooked into the project. Cause you are right, when I take the Response.Write() and place it in one of the other files it works.

Answer (score 3):

Use *breakpoints*. Set a breakpoint at the end of your method by clicking in the "gutter" area. A red circle will appear that looks like this:

[image: Breakpoint is set]

Now run your program in debug mode by clicking the button with the green triangle or pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>. The program will run, producing the output in the console (a separate window). Once it hits your breakpoint, you can examine the console for the output, like this:

[image: Breakpoint is hit]

Comment: When I try to insert a breakpoint I get this message. "A breakpoint could not be inserted at this location".

Comment: @japanFour You may need to re-build your program in order for the VS-2010 to "understand" that it is OK to set the breakpoint on the line where you are setting it.

Comment: Still no luck after re-build.

Comment: You should read his comments in his original post. he did not make a console app, it is a ASP.NET page.

Comment: @japanFour "I did my project as ASP.NET MVC3 using VS 2010" That's the problem then. You need to create a "console application" project in order to see the output to console.

Comment: Okay well I guess maybe I am mistaken as to how I should debug. I would like to use MVC3 so is there a different way I should test my pages in an ASP.NET MVC3 project?

Comment: @japanFour Your program will be different with ASP.NET MVC3: there will be no `Main` in the traditional sense; you will need to use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` instead of `Console.WriteLine`, and so on. Breakpoints would continue to work, though.

Comment: I was able to insert the breakpoint but I still get nothing when using System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello World");

Comment: @japanFour Has your breakpoint been hit (it would look like the second picture, with the yellow arrow in the red circle). The output of `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` goes to the debug window of VS-2010; you wouldn't see it unless your code comes to that breakpoint, though.

Comment: Nope it doesn't appear to have been hit.

Comment: @japanFour Work through the tutorial for ASP.NET (see Scott Chamberlain's answer for a link) to see where you need to put your code in order for it to be executed and breakpoints to be hit.

Comment: I will take a look at it. I was hoping to try to learn as much as I could from the web. But I might have to break down and buy a book.

Comment: @japanFour The web version of that tutorial seems fine, you may not need a paper book if you work through it.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading a tutorial for Console Application, however you are trying to create a ASP.NET application. I would reccomend reading a [tutorial for ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615484%28v=vs.88%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Like many before said: it goes by too fast, so either use breakpoints, or use a Read...

You can also write to your Visual Studio output window with [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.write.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

you need to put break point over the line which you want to debug 
short cut to placing break point is ctrl D,n
then you can step over or step into the code with f10 and f11 function keys